# How to save a graph through command line with Gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

`gnuplot -p -e "plot [-4:4] exp(-x**2 / 2); set terminal png size 400,300; set output 'xyz.png'"`

That's what I have tried. It does create the png, but corrupted.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You must set the terminal and the output file name before plotting:

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal png size 400,300; set output 'xyz.png'; plot [-4:4] exp(-x**2 / 2)"
```

In that case you also don't need the `persist` flag.

Comment: Ah.  semicolons instead of \n - I see how this works.

Comment: Is it possible to have all of the commands in a script and just pass the output filename from the command line? I haven't used gnuplot for years and can't remember. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The order of your commands. First set the terminal. Then set the output. Finally plot.